# My confirm popup is still deleting an object whether ok or cancel is clicked. Why? Angular to blame?

Tags: javascript, angular, button, onclick, alert

I'm trying to create a popup that gives a user the option of hitting ok or cancel upon clicking a delete button.  However, even if the user presses cancel it still deletes it.  Not sure what I can do about that.  Is it some weird thing about using AngularJS? Here's my code:
`<button onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');" ng-click="vm.deleteTask(task)">Delete</button>`

Answer (score 1):

No angular is not to blame.

You are using `ng-click` and `onclick` & both of them will independently work.

Use only `ng-click`

```
<button ng-click="vm.deleteTask(task)">Delete</button>
```

Inside this function `deleteTask` call the `confirm`

```
deleteTask = function(param){
    var confirmStatus = confirm('Are you sure?');
     // will be trur if ok button is pressed or false
    if(confirmStatus){
       // code to delete the task
    }
   else {
     // do what ever
     }
   }
```

Comment: Thank you!  All of this is new to me, but not being able to use both onclick and ng-click makes perfect sense.

Comment: onclick is javascript click event.Where as ng-click angular click event written on top of onclick. So you can use ng-click freely